# How do I get the @ sign so I can type @override in my Java code?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make an Android App that way I can make a lot of money.

But I need some symbols that I can't figure out how to create.

One of the symbols is @ <-- How do I make this? I've been copying/pasting it the entire time.

Please help...

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to type @ on your keyboard? That's not really a programming question. (It's also not clear how "I'm trying to make an Android App that way I can make a lot of money" is at all relevant to the question.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about how to use a keyboard (apparently)

Comment: This is not a Java programming question.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how do you type your own email adress? For usernames etc...

Comment: You are trolling right? How did you type in your email address to sign up here?

Comment: you should press left Alt+ left ctrl and the press 2.

Comment: You are the author of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422499/possible-proof-int-1-infty-frac1x-dx-converges) with a ton of markup characters but cant find the ``@``?

Comment: @f1sh good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be SHIFT + 2 on a standard American Keyboard

Comment: Nah that didn't work... :(

Comment: If you're using a different keyboard that doesn't have the @ symbol on the 2 key for some reason (unicode experts: does that exist? edit: it does. British have @ above ' to the right of the; key)  You may still be able to use the alt code. Hold alt and press 6 then 4, then release alt.

Comment: @TheAtomicOption That worked for me! It sucks that I'll have to do that over and over again although

Comment: @ should appear *somewhere* on pretty much any keyboard layout. You should find out what your keyboard layout is, and then you can type it normally. On Win10, you can find the name of the layout listed under Control Panel-->Language